# Add different linetypes in ggplot2/ggroc in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use different linetypes in `ggplot` using `ggroc` – but I can't get `scale_linetype_manual` to work. Please see example code below.

```
library(pROC)
library(ggplot2)

# Example data

# Perfect 
probs_1 <- seq(0, 1, length.out=10000)
roc_perfect <- roc(probs_1, probs_1)

# Random 
probs_1 <- rep(c(1, 0), 100)
probs_2 <- c(rep(c(0, 1), 50), 
             rep(c(1, 0), 50))
roc_random <- roc(probs_1, probs_2)

# AUC = 82
set.seed(144)
probs_82 <- seq(0, 1, length.out=10000)
truth_82 <- runif(10000)^1.21 < probs
roc_82 <- roc(truth_82, probs_82)



# Plot ROC curves
pROC::ggroc(list(roc_perfect, roc_82, roc_random), 
            legacy.axes = FALSE,
            #  linetype=1, 
            linewidth = 0.4) + 
  # Does not work
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(2, 1, 2)) +
  
  scale_colour_manual("", 
                      labels = c("Perfect", 
                                 "Model",
                                 "Random classification"), 
                      values = c("gray",
                                 "green", 
                                 "gray")) +
  theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, you need to indicate which aesthetics are used in the function. Over your code, it should look like this:

```
pROC::ggroc(list(roc_perfect, roc_82, roc_random), 
            aes = c("colour", 
                    "linetype"),
            legacy.axes = FALSE,
            linewidth = 0.4) +
  scale_linetype_manual("",
                        values=c(2, 1, 2),
                        labels = c("Perfect", 
                                   "Model",
                                   "Random classification")) +
  scale_colour_manual("", 
                      labels = c("Perfect", 
                                 "Model",
                                 "Random classification"), 
                      values = c("gray",
                                 "green", 
                                 "gray")) +
  theme_classic()
```

As a result, I got the following plot.

[image]

Comment: great, but please note that now there are two legends.

Comment: I just focused on showing the linetype, but it can be solved by including the same legend name and labels as in `scale_colour_manual`. I mean, with 
`scale_linetype_manual("", values=c(2, 1, 2), labels = c("Perfect", "Model", "Random classification"))`

Comment: I added it to the complete answer.